# In the network tab of Firefox's developer tools, is it possible to show endpoint's names in the list view?

Tags: web, firefox, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

I'm using Firefox. When I access `POST example.com/oauth2/token`, the Network tab of the developer tools says `Domain == example.com` and `File == token` in the list view (left half).

When I click the entry, the details are shown in the separate window (right half). It says `Filename == /oauth2/token`.

How is it possible to show the full name of the endpoint (i.e. `Filename`) in the list view? For example, I'd like to sort entries by the names of the endpoints (rather than the last components).

[image]